# X equals Y WHEN a==b and equals Z WHEN b==c in Python

Tags: python

Here is what I am trying to do:

The dataframe contains the standard financial market values of D1 of EURUSD.

```
df = symbol_data("EURUSD","D1")
price = df["close"].iloc[-100:]

op = df['open'].iloc[-100:]
hi = df['high'].iloc[-100:]
lo = df['low'].iloc[-100:]
cl = df['close'].iloc[-100:]

max_idx = list(argrelextrema(hi.values, np.greater, order=10)[0])
min_idx = list(argrelextrema(lo.values, np.less, order=10)[0])
idx = max_idx + min_idx
idx.sort()

peaks = hi.values[max_idx] if max_idx == idx and lo.values[min_idx] if min_idx==idx
```

I want the peaks to equal to the high values **when** I have a max **and** equal to the low values **when** I have a min and also I want them to be **ordered** by the index as well.

Meaning:

```
high_peaks = hi.values[max_idx]
low_peaks = lo.values[min_idx]
```

Need a sorted mixture of these in peaks:

```
peaks = high_peaks and low_peaks
```

For example:

```
max_idx = [4, 31, 72, 97]
min_idx = [18, 43, 67]

idx = [4, 18, 31, 43, 67, 72, 97]


high_peaks = array([1.10947, 1.14955, 1.10167, 1.13829])
low_peaks = array([1.07772, 1.0635 , 1.07263])
```

I need this:

```
peaks = array([1.10947, 1.07772, 1.14955, 1.0635, 1.07263, 1.10167, 1.13829])
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Please clarify *need a sorted mixture* by giving an example input and the desired output, as Python code -- so that it's possible to understand what you need, and it's possible to verify that an answer indeed does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This answer puts either `hi.values[max_idx]` or `lo.values[min_idx]` (but never a mixture) or None to `peaks`.

```
peaks = hi.values[max_idx] if max_idx == idx else lo.values[min_idx] if min_idx == idx else None
```

Equivalently:

```
if max_idx == idx:
  peaks = hi.values[max_idx]
elif min_idx == idx:
  peaks = lo.values[min_idx]
else:
  peaks = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it returns None. Any insight?

Comment: The code in the answer correctly implements the condition you ask for (I've just double checked in a Python interpreter). You are getting None because both `... == idx` are false.  To debug that, print max_idx, min_idx and idx and see if they have what you need.

Comment: If max_idx, min_idx or idx is incorrect, and it's not obvious for you how to fix them, feel free to ask another question about that on StackOverflow, in a separate question.

Comment: max_idx and min_idx are correct and idx has both max_idx and min_idx inside.
Even when I do this:
high_peaks = hi.values[max_idx],  
low_peaks = lo.values[min_idx]
I get correct values, but I need all numbers in one array!

Comment: Is it clear what I am trying to achieve or should I rephrase it in the main question?
Let me know so I can correct it because I still haven't found an answer of how to join these two sorted on one array.

Comment: OK, I understand now that you want a mixture of `hi.values[max_idx]` and `lo.values[min_idx]` in `peaks`, and this answer doesn't give you that. To get what you want, please extend the question by adding example code which initializes `hi = ...` and `lo = ...` and also contains a `print(desired_peaks)` and also the desired output of that. Based on these details, it will be possible to understand the requirements and give you an answer.